Spring Boot: The 5.5.5 version for [org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect] is no longer supported. How to resolve this issue
I'm working on a Spring Boot application and encountered the following warning message during startup:
HHH000511: The 5.5.5 version for [org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect] is no longer supported, hence certain features may not work properly. The minimum supported version is 8.0.0. Check the community dialects project for available legacy versions.
I'm using Hibernate ORM version 6.5.2.Final and MySQL database. How can I resolve this issue? Should I upgrade my MySQL version or modify some configuration? Any guidance would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

most likely update your mysql jdbc driver to the last version - can't tell you more without seeing pom.xml

Starting from Hibernate version 6.0, legacy dialects like MySQL5Dialect have been moved to a separate artifact, called hibernate-community-dialects. If you are using an old MySQL database version, upgrading the driver won't help - since Hibernate obtains the dialect version that has to be used by inquiring the server.
Try to add this artifact:
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate.orm</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-community-dialects</artifactId>
    <version>6.5.2.Final</version>
</dependency>

And set the dialect in the properties as:
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.community.dialect.MySQL55Dialect

For MySQL, in that artifact there are the following dialects: MySQL5Dialect, MySQL55Dialect, MySQL57Dialect.

Use latest MySQL driver dependency:
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.mysql</groupId>
    <artifactId>mysql-connector-j</artifactId>
    <version>9.0.0</version>
</dependency>

(Remove the other dependency)
